# Postgres index creation for jsonb column having JSON Array value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, indexing

I have an employee table in postgres having a JSON column "mobile" in it. It stores JSON Array value ,

```
e_id(integer)  name(char)   mobile(jsonb)
1              John         [{\"mobile\": \"1234567891\", \"status\": \"verified\"},{\"mobile\": \"1265439872\",\"status\": \"verified\"}]
2              Ben          [{\"mobile\": \"6453637238\", \"status\": \"verified\"},{\"mobile\": \"4437494900\",\"status\": \"verified\"}]
```

I have a search api which queries this table to search for employee using mobile number.

How can I query mobile numbers directly ?
How should I **create index on the jsonb column** to make query work faster ?

*updated question

Comment: Index is useful only when the jsonb column value is going to be repeated. Question is, does the jsonb column will have many duplicate values ?

Comment: yes it will be having many duplicates in my case. This is an example scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query like this:

```
SELECT e_id, name
FROM employees
WHERE mobile @> '[{"mobile": "1234"}]';
```

The following index would help:

```
CREATE INDEX ON employees USING gin (mobile);
```

Comment: I have used the same query but it always returns 0 rows as result.

Comment: Is it because when i look at the data using select * , i see mobile columns like below,"[{\"mobile\": \”1234567891\”, \"status\": \"verified\"}, {\"mobile\": \"1265439872\", \"status\": \"verified\"}]"

Comment: Well, it works for me. Perhaps you are not using `jsonb` after all, or you have some whitespace somewhere, or something else. Perhaps you should come up with a reproducible test case and add that to the question.

Comment: What program are you using to look at the data?

Comment: using terminal only

Comment: describe table shows mobile column type as jsonb only. And while inserting data( django api) it passes normal JSON array without any /. Internally / is added to this while inserting into postgres.

Comment: Yes, it is JSON. But rather than inserting a JSON array that contains a number of objects, you inserted a single string. Notice how the value starts with `"` and all other `"` are escaped. So the problem must be in the Django code.